# How can I find the startIndex of a substring in a Google Docs using the the Python API

Tags: python, api, rest, google-docs-api

[Following the Google Docs API documentation recommendation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/merge), I've created a document template, containing "*placeholders*" such as `{{my_text_goes_here}}` in order to use the `replaceAllText` request to substitute the placeholder with my own text. So far so good.

However, not only I want to insert new text, but I also want to format it. My problem is to retrieve the `startIndex` of this new text (or of the previous placeholder). There aren't any `find` or `locate` request in the API.

I've tried to retrieve the text of the whole document ([guide here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/extract-text)), find the position of my placeholder in the text, and use it as the `startIndex` for the formatting of my new text *(using the `updateTextStyle` request)*.
Unfortunately, this value is incorrect and the format isn't applied where it should be. I suppose it might have to do with UTF-16 encoding or some hidden character...

What I'm trying to do is a very basic action but it requires such complex code to achieve that it renders the whole API useless, except for basic invoice combination (which we could already do 20 years ago with Word and Outlook...)

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1):

Might not be as basic as you would like it to be, but what you can do:

**Use the method [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) setting fields to `body/content/paragraph/elements(startIndex,textRun/content)`.**

This will return you a JSON of type:

```
{
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {},
      {
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 1,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "freter"
              }
            },
            {
              "startIndex": 7,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "\n"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 8,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "Htrhyt "
              }
            },
            {
              "startIndex": 15,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "{{my_text_goes_here}}"
              }
            },
            {
              "startIndex": 36,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "  gtrtry\n"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can programmaticaly the content of each `textRun` against `{{my_text_goes_here}}` and retrieve the `startIndex` of the matching elements .

For the sample above your result would be:

```
           {
              "startIndex": 15,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "{{my_text_goes_here}}"
              }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka! It's also the solution I'm implementing right now. It looks like the only way.
A very easy solution would be to also return the `startIndex` from the `replaceAllText` request.

Comment: To whome it can help, this is the jsonPath Expression used to retrieve the startIndex, given a TOKEN:
`json_path = f"$[*].paragraph.elements[?(@.textRun.content ~ '{TOKEN}')].startIndex"`